# PHP Use 'eval' As a Function (Get Return Value)

Tags: php, 4d-database

## Background

I'm using a [4D server](http://www.4d.com). 4D has a built in [PHP processor](http://doc.4d.com/4Dv15/4D/15/PHP-Execute.301-2006299.en.html), but in an odd way. I have to start an inline 4D script in my webpage, then I have to call up `PHP Execute`, and give it the path of a `.php` file.

**4D Script**

```
C_TEXT($result)
C_BOOLEAN($isOK)
$isOK:=PHP Execute("C:\\php\\myPHPFile.php";"my_function";$result)
ALERT($Result)
```

**myPHPFile.php**

```
<?php
    function my_function() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
?>
```

### Goal

I want to be able to write this in my webiste:

```
<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>
```

And have it processed. I almost have it figured out. If I first convert it via the server code (4D can do that) to this:

```
C_TEXT($result)
C_BOOLEAN($isOK)
$isOK:=PHP Execute("";"echo 'Hello World'";$result)
ALERT($Result)
```

You are supposed to be able to run PHP native functions directly without a `.php` file. You'd think that would work. Turns out it doesn't.

So I tried this:

```
C_TEXT($result)
C_BOOLEAN($isOK)
$isOK:=PHP Execute("";"echo";$result;"Hello World") // I can send parameters
ALERT($Result)
```

Still doesn't work. Turns out that I need to evaluate the code using a function.

```
C_TEXT($result)
C_BOOLEAN($isOK)
$isOK:=PHP Execute("";"eval";$result;"return 'Hello World;'") // I can send parameters
ALERT($Result)
```

That SHOULD send `"return 'Hello World';"` to `eval()`. Well that STILL doesn't work, because I've found out that `eval()` isn't actually a function. So what I need to know, after all that background, is this:

## Question

Is there a native function in PHP that would work like this:

```
$evaulatedCode = eval($unEvaluatedCode);
```

Comment: Just, out of curiosity, where is `$Result` declared/initialized?

Comment: `C_TEXT($result)` is the declaration.

Comment: Yes, that is why I need a function that would work like `eval`, so that I can put it in there.

Comment: To answer the question part `eval("\$evaulatedCode = $unEvaluatedCode");`

Comment: Never heard about that. If you ask me, one of the things you don't need for web development is that proprietary 4D stuff.

Comment: Abra, would the `$evaluatedCode` be returned?

Comment: hek, the main reason I'm asking is so that on the web pages, I can just write PHP instead of having to write in the proprietary 4D stuff.

Comment: No `$evaluatedCode` will be assigned the return of the evaluated code and be available in global scope.  I was answering the stated question, I have no knowledge of 4D.

Comment: @AndyM Got your point. Believe me, I've worked >10 years in web dev but I've never heard of 4D before. I guess you are doing it on customer's request. (I pity you in that case!) Otherwise I would simply not use that 4D stuff. (Note that I've removed the 4d tag, because it relates to 4d in the sense of 4 dimensions. Check the tag description.)

Comment: If you want to capture the *output* of eval, then use `ob_start` etc. and `eval("?>$script<?php");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, you have the semicolon in the wrong place in your `return` statement. Try this:

```
$isOK:=PHP Execute("";"eval";$result;"return 'Hello World';")
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `eval` was my first thought too, as I explained in the question. But `eval` isn't a function. It doesn't return a value. I think as I review this more that it isn't possible to do what I want.

Comment: Actually, now that I recheck the documentation, I think your `return` statement should have worked. The manual says: _eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to return is returned._

Comment: That's odd then that it doesn't work. I'm wondering if 4D just isn't treating the eval statement as an official "function".

Comment: I suppose anything is possible if it has its own PHP interpreter instead of using the real thing. Did you fix the semicolon as I showed? You had it inside the single quotes.